# 2007 Kia Spectra engine temperature fluctuating

Tags: engine, ac, cooling-system, kia, spectra

what would cause my kia's engine temperature to start fluctuating. it never gets hot but it will rise 2 bars on the temp gage and when it rises to the second bar over where it normally reads my ac will quit blowing cold air. if I turn the car off and turn it back on it will start blowing cold air again but only for a few seconds if the temperature doesn't start to go down. if the temperature goes down below that that second bar it will keep blowing cold air. the temperature will go back to its normal reading then back up then back down and like I said it never gets over 2 bars higher than normal. I hope I've explained my problem to where it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Is the temperature getting higher only when it is warm out or is it a constant problem the just started?

With it being several years old can you advise as to last time your had the cooling system flushed and new antifreeze added.  The cooling system clogs with age and can reduce the effectiveness causing a rise in operating temperature.  Some engines have a thermal switch to stop the AC system to prevent overheating the engine.

Another area could be the thermostat is starting to fail and not opening proper when temperature gets to the operating zone.

Have your system flushed, coolant changed and pressure tested.

Answer (score 1):

It was my thermostat! Hope this helps somebody else one day